# While I am trying to access my db(MySQL) from play framework, I am getting this error while coding:"The import play.db cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, jdeveloper

So what should I do next? An it would be great if some one could guide me in connecting MySQL with play.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the proper dependency. Since you are using Java, you need to add the following one:

```
libraryDependencies += javaJdbc
```

See more details about the dependency here:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-java-jdbc_2.12/2.6.11

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:
**Add the below code in build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(javaJdbc)
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.8-dmr"
libraryDependencies += evolutions
```

And then in your **plugins.sbt** if you are using Ebean then

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.0.3")
```

else, other Java Persistence framework.

Then make sure in your **application.conf** you have the following entries:

```
play.evolutions {
   db.default.enabled = false
}
db{
   default.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
   default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name?useSSL=false"
   default.username="u_name"
   default.password="u_pass"
}
play.db{
   hikaricp.minimumIdle = 50
   hikaricp.maximumPoolSize = 50
}
ebean.default = ["models.*"]
```

**Finally do make a schema using MySQL workbench (considering you are using MySQL) in your db to access it from within your application**